# Missing options when compiling LLVM

Tags: llvm

When I'm using the LLVM package from by distribution (archlinux), I've got multiple command line options availables (I'm using `llvm-link -help` to see them).

```
OPTIONS:
  -asm-verbose                                 - Add comments to directives.
  -cppfname=<function name>                    - Specify the name of the generated function
  -cppfor=<string>                             - Specify the name of the thing to generate
  -cppgen                                      - Choose what kind of output to generate
    =program                                   -   Generate a complete program
    =module                                    -   Generate a module definition
    =contents                                  -   Generate contents of a module
    =function                                  -   Generate a function definition
    =functions                                 -   Generate all function definitions
    =inline                                    -   Generate an inline function
    =variable                                  -   Generate a variable definition
    =type                                      -   Generate a type definition
  -disable-spill-fusing                        - Disable fusing of spill code into instructions
  -enable-correct-eh-support                   - Make the -lowerinvoke pass insert expensive, but correct, EH code

  ... many more ...
```

However, when building LLVM from sources, I didn't get those options :

```
OPTIONS:
  -f                - Enable binary output on terminals
  -help             - Display available options (-help-hidden for more)
  -o=<filename>     - Override output filename
  -print-after-all  - Print IR after each pass
  -print-before-all - Print IR before each pass
  -stats            - Enable statistics output from program
  -time-passes      - Time each pass, printing elapsed time for each on exit
  -v                - Print information about actions taken
  -verify-dom-info  - Verify dominator info (time consuming)
  -verify-loop-info - Verify loop info (time consuming)
  -version          - Display the version of this program
```

Why ?

Comment: Try
    
      llvm-link -help-hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is broken with the build provided by your distribution. The help output you show (the first one) is definitely the bogus one. You should report bug to archlinux.